# Using MongoDB Native Dot Notation with variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have following command:

```
collection.update(
   { "facebook_id": req.params.facebook_id }, 
   { "$push": { "circles.0.messages": message } }, function(err) {...});
```

That works fine. But I need the 0 to be a variable. As soon as I change it to:

```
collection.update(
    {"facebook_id": req.params.facebook_id },
    { "$push": { "circles.j.messages": message } }, function(err) {...});
```

It doesn't work anymore. There is no error, but nothing is being pushed.
Tries like:

```
  collection.update(
      {"facebook_id':req.params.facebook_id }, 
      { "$push": { "circles."+j+"j.messages": message } }, function(err) {...});
```

also won't work.

How can I use a variable in Dot Notation?

Thanks & Best,
Marc

Comment: I think you may be looking for the `$` positional operator? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Answer (score 0):

As @mnemosyn mentioned:

```
collection.update(
    {"facebook_id": req.params.facebook_id, "circles.field" : value }, 
    { "$push": { "circles.$.messages": message } }, function(err) {...});
```

works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I find the answers you got rather unsatisfying, this is how it can be done: 
Hardcoded in shell:

```
"objectName.nestedObjectname";
```

With variable:

```
let myVar = "nestedObjectname"; 
[`objectName.${myVar}`];
```